# Caching dynamic content from Tomcat through Apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, caching, mod-jk, mod-cache

I would like to cache dynamic content coming from Tomcat. However, the lifespan of the content is pretty short (max 15 minutes) before an update is needed. Would this be possible using something like mod_cache?